# 3inch vs 4inch PVC drain for a bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage, drain-waste-vent, drains

3inch or 4inch PVC for my bathroom?

During a remodel of my bathroom we had the old 4inch cast iron drain (vent was also 4 inches) removed.

It’s just a single bathroom with 1 toilet 1 sink and 1 shower/tub. The kitchen connects right before it leaves the home at a 4 inch line.

Should I put a 4 inch line back or downsize it to a 3 inch line?

I am worried that with a 4inch pipe it would be too high to connect to a p trap for the tub. The old tub was connected to a drum trap and that drain line was pretty much at the height of the finish floor -1inch or so.

3 inch PVC slope

I am trying to keep the pipe in the 2x10 (actual 9.5) joists. I think if I did 3 inch I could have it sit lower in the joists giving more depth for the tub p trap.

I at first read that 3 inch needs 1/4inch per foot of slope and 4 needs just 1/8 but now I’m reading that 3 inch also just needs 1/8 inch per foot of slope.

Is that true? Should I downsize to 3 inch and would that help my situation?

Comment: code is 1/4" of slope per foot.  4" pipe gives longer critical trap arm length on p-traps.